# SQL OPENROWSET Not returning all columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

Everyone. Really need helps to solve my problem.
I've 2 excel file with .xls extension (nota.xls and agt.xls). The first one have 30 columns and the other one only 2 columns. I want to read those from SQL Server with this code:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0','Excel 8.0;Database=C:\nota.xls;IMEX=1;HDR=YES;','SELECT * FROM [sheet1$]')
```

But the result from that code is only showing one column. Actually the nota.xls have 2 columns.
The result:

|NoTrans|

Expectation:

|NoTrans|Trans|

It happens too with the agt.xls. Which have 30 columns but only shown 29. I've searching the solution but no ones work. Some site said to change the HDR properties to NO. HDR=NO. But it is not work at all. :(

Comment: Sorry forget to mention I'm using SQL Server 2000 and MS Excel 2003.

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19632567/sql-openrowset-with-excel?rq=1

Try inserting it as .CSV (See Above Answer)

And try to upgrade your architecture as soon as you can i.e. Excel 2007 / SQL Server 2008R2, or higher.